# create attribute set in Magento setup script

Tags: php, magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

Creating attributes and assigning them to existing attribute sets is a solved problem but we are running into an issue trying to create an attribute set and populate it with default and specific attributes is failing. This is the code in use:

```
$setup->addAttributeSet('catalog_product', 'women_sizing_denim');

$oAttributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")
        ->load($setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'women_sizing_denim'))
        ->initFromSkeleton($setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'default'))
        ->save();
```

I can verify by debugging through that the `initfromSkeleton` method does load the attributes from the default attribute_set as advertised, however after the `save()`, the new set is empty.

Adding new attributes to the set is possible, so it does exist and is created correctly, but the missing default attributes make it unusable since SKU, price, name, etc are all required.

Answer (score 5):

I remember that the issue with creating attribute sets based on the default attribute set was, that you need to save the attribute set *twice*, once before calling `initSkeleton()` and once after it.

I don't remember the exact reason anymore, it's too long ago. Anyway, here's what worked for me:

```
// Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
$oEntitySetup = $this;
$oEntitySetup->startSetup();

$sNewSetName = 'myset';
$iCatalogProductEntityTypeId = (int) $oEntitySetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');

$oAttributeset = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId($iCatalogProductEntityTypeId)
    ->setAttributeSetName($sNewSetName);

if ($oAttributeset->validate()) {
    $oAttributeset
        ->save()
        ->initFromSkeleton($iCatalogProductEntityTypeId)
        ->save();
}
else {
    die('Attributeset with name ' . $sNewSetName . ' already exists.');
}

$oEntitySetup->endSetup();
```

Comment: thanks Jurgen, will give that a try. I have seen other instances where a Magento object needed to be saved before modifications, its not logical, but definitely possible!

Comment: Saving twice was the real issue for me. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that setup class needs to extend

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
```

so that

```
$oEntitySetup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
```

can be called.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jürgen Thelen answer which worked.

But I found the new attribute set did not have default options and options group such as general and invoice etc.

So to get round this include $installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'default') in the initFromSkeleton()

```
if($attributeSet->validate()) {
$attributeSet
    ->save()
    ->initFromSkeleton($installer->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'default'))
    ->save();
} else {
die('Attributeset with name ' . $setName . ' already exists.');
}
```