# Creating Attribute set is taking time because of “initFromSkeleton”

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have written a script to create attribute set and attribute from csv and it worked fine on my localhost but after uploading it to server I found that it is taking so much time to do the job even with 1 entry. So I was debugging it and I found out that "initFromSkeleton" is taking time.

```
    $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                    ->setType('catalog_product')
                    ->getTypeId(); // 4 - Default 

    $newSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set');
    $newSet->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
    $newSet->setAttributeSetName($setName);
    $newSet->save();

    $newSet->initFromSkeleton($entityTypeId);
    $newSet->save();
```

I don't know what to do because to build new attribute based on default attribute set I have to write this initFromSkeleton. While searching google I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095436/create-attribute-set-in-magento-setup-script). But it understood from there.

Could any one has done this before. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used the same code and it didn't took much time for me. I have created 90 attribute set within 20 minutes in server.

Comment: if you seen my answer give some response

Answer (score 1):

Disable automatic updating of indexes to improve performance.Change the index update mode to manual.